# C# Cake NuGet License Verifier

Tags: c#, cakebuild

I'm using cake to build my csproj projects. Since package usage via NuGet is very simple, you'll end up with multiple dependencies to third party NuGet packages. Since the code is used in a commercial manner, I want to extend my build script via a license checker. Does anybody knows if there is a license checker available for Cake? For Maven there is a plugin available [here](https://github.com/AyoyAB/Ayoy-Maven-License-Verifier-Plugin).

I checked the cake online [reference](https://cakebuild.net/dsl/) but was not able to find a "module" like this.

I also queried stackoverflow and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022013/finding-third-party-licenses-with-nuget), which doesn't help me, because it uses the Visual Studio build in package manager, that is a seperate PowerShell host and can't be created/started from default PowerShell host.

Thx.

Comment: No there isn't any license verifier. But I made a tool that can help you make your own tool. It's called dotnet-thirdpartynotices and it's on github.

Comment: Ok, cool, thx. I'll check it out.